# Every proper ideal can be written as a product of maximal ideals in PID (product and intersection)

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

**$R$ is a P.I.D.
Show that every proper ideal can be written as a product $P_{1}P_{2}...P_{k}$ of maximal ideals and this writing is unique. *(Don't take my question as a dublicate because I ask about something different)***

$R$ PID $\Rightarrow  R$ UFD.

Every proper ideal in PID has the form $(a)$ for $a\in R$. I am in UFD so $a=ux_{1}x_{2}...x_{n}$, $u \in U(R) , x_{i}$ irreducible. I want to show that $(a) = (x_{1})(x_{2})...(x_{n})$.

$(\subseteq)$: I have $c \in (a)$ then $c=ya=yux_{1}x_{2}...x_{n}$ for $y \in R$ so $c \in (x_{1})(x_{2})...(x_{n})$

$(\supseteq )$: I have $c \in (x_{1})(x_{2})...(x_{n})$ then $c=wq_{1}q_{2}...q_{n}$, $w \in R, q_{i} \in (x_{i})$.

and $q_{i} \in (x_{i})$ so there is $k_{i}$ such that $q_{i}=k_{i}x_{i}$

Finally $c=w(k_{1}x_{1})(k_{2}x_{2})...(k_{n}x_{n}) = w(k_{1}k_{2}...k_{n})(x_{1}x_{2}...x_{n}) = w(k_{1}k_{2}...k_{n})a \in (a)$

so $(a) = (x_{1})(x_{2})...(x_{n})$.

**The problem is that I think I am missing something. Is everything ok? A friend of mine told me that I should also write that the product $P_{1}P_{2}...P_{n}$ is in the intersection $P_{1} \cap P_{2} \cap ... \cap P_{n}$ but I can't see why and I don't know how**

Comment: Isn't a statement as the one to be proved here rather often a *step* in the proof of "PID$\implies$ UFD)?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for any finitely generated ideals $I = (a_1, \dots, a_m)$ and $J = (b_1, \dots, b_m)$ of a commutative ring, we have that $IJ = (a_i b_j \,|\, 1 \leq i \leq m \text{ and } 1 \leq j \leq n).$ (Check out the first answer provided in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648061/finite-generating-set-of-the-product-of-finitely-generated-ideals), for instance.) Considering that your ring $R$ is a PID, it is by definition a commutative ring, hence we have that $(a) = (ux_1 \cdots x_n) = (x_1 \cdots x_n) = (x_1) \cdots (x_n),$ as desired.